# Adding "else" at the end of an if-else statement

Tags: c, embedded

Some of my co-workers tend to add an empty else at the end of the if-else statement. (even though no logic is implemented there)
Like so:

```
if(X)
{
... // some logic
}
else if(Y)
{
... // some logic
}
else if(Z)
{
... // some logic
}
else
{ 
;
}
```

what is the benefit of adding the last else with ';' inside?

Comment: may be to show explicitly nothing has to be done in the else case ? Why you do not ask them ? ;-)

Comment: It's to fullfill MISRA rule 14.10